# How do I mark my question as answered if I was not a registered when I asked it?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, unregistered-users

I asked a question yesterday without signing up.  Now that I want to go back and comment or mark a response as the answer I cannot.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: What's the URL for the question?

Answer (score 4):

Write to team@stackoverflow.com, or flag the question for moderator review -- you need to request that your original account get merged with your new (registered) one.